# PHP Multiplication Table -- Need for loop to add a row (16x16)

Tags: php

My goal is to get my PHP Multiplication table to look like this: [9x9 array with "x" and bolded numbers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/955ch.jpg):

[image]

but instead, my array currently looks like this:[9x9 array with x on the top row and no bolded numbers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zY6nE.jpg)

Here is my code so far:

[image]

```
<?php
echo "<table border =\"1\" style='border-collapse: collapse'>"; //creating the border outline
echo "<td> x </td>";
for ($row=1; $row <= 16; $row++) {  // first loop
echo "<tr> \n";
for ($col=1; $col <= 16; $col++) { //2nd loop
  $p = $col * $row; //computing values
  echo "<td>$p</td> \n";
  }
     echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>"; //closing the table
?>
```

I know I need a third for loop to help bold the numbers in the first row and first column, as well as properly include the "x" so that it is not on top of my array like it currently is. Can anyone help me fix this issue? Thanks! :)

Answer (score 1):

You have to add the first row and column. Like:

```
<?php
echo "<table border =\"1\" style='border-collapse: collapse'>"; //creating the border outline

    //Add the first row
    echo "<tr style='font-weight: bold;'>";
        echo "<td >X</td> \n";
        for ($col=1; $col <= 16; $col++) {
            echo "<td>$col</td> \n";
        }
    echo "</tr>";

    for ($row=1; $row <= 16; $row++) {  // first loop
        echo "<tr> \n";

        //Adding the first column
        echo "<td style='font-weight: bold;'>$row</td>";

        for ($col=1; $col <= 16; $col++) {
            $p = $col * $row; //computing values
            echo "<td>$p</td> \n";
        }

        echo "</tr>";
    }
echo "</table>"; //closing the table
?>
```

This will result to:

```html
<table style="border-collapse: collapse" border="1"><tr style="font-weight: bold;"><td>X</td> 
<td>1</td> 
<td>2</td> 
<td>3</td> 
<td>4</td> 
<td>5</td> 
<td>6</td> 
<td>7</td> 
<td>8</td> 
<td>9</td> 
<td>10</td> 
<td>11</td> 
<td>12</td> 
<td>13</td> 
<td>14</td> 
<td>15</td> 
<td>16</td> 
</tr><tr> 
<td style="font-weight: bold;">1</td><td>1</td> 
<td>2</td> 
<td>3</td> 
<td>4</td> 
<td>5</td> 
<td>6</td> 
<td>7</td> 
<td>8</td> 
<td>9</td> 
<td>10</td> 
<td>11</td> 
<td>12</td> 
<td>13</td> 
<td>14</td> 
<td>15</td> 
<td>16</td> 
</tr><tr> 
<td style="font-weight: bold;">2</td><td>2</td> 
<td>4</td> 
<td>6</td> 
<td>8</td> 
<td>10</td> 
<td>12</td> 
<td>14</td> 
<td>16</td> 
<td>18</td> 
<td>20</td> 
<td>22</td> 
<td>24</td> 
<td>26</td> 
<td>28</td> 
<td>30</td> 
<td>32</td> 
</tr><tr> 
<td style="font-weight: bold;">3</td><td>3</td> 
<td>6</td> 
<td>9</td> 
<td>12</td> 
<td>15</td> 
<td>18</td> 
<td>21</td> 
<td>24</td> 
<td>27</td> 
<td>30</td> 
<td>33</td> 
<td>36</td> 
<td>39</td> 
<td>42</td> 
<td>45</td> 
<td>48</td> 
</tr><tr> 
<td style="font-weight: bold;">4</td><td>4</td> 
<td>8</td> 
<td>12</td> 
<td>16</td> 
<td>20</td> 
<td>24</td> 
<td>28</td> 
<td>32</td> 
<td>36</td> 
<td>40</td> 
<td>44</td> 
<td>48</td> 
<td>52</td> 
<td>56</td> 
<td>60</td> 
<td>64</td> 
</tr><tr> 
<td style="font-weight: bold;">5</td><td>5</td> 
<td>10</td> 
<td>15</td> 
<td>20</td> 
<td>25</td> 
<td>30</td> 
<td>35</td> 
<td>40</td> 
<td>45</td> 
<td>50</td> 
<td>55</td> 
<td>60</td> 
<td>65</td> 
<td>70</td> 
<td>75</td> 
<td>80</td> 
</tr><tr> 
<td style="font-weight: bold;">6</td><td>6</td> 
<td>12</td> 
<td>18</td> 
<td>24</td> 
<td>30</td> 
<td>36</td> 
<td>42</td> 
<td>48</td> 
<td>54</td> 
<td>60</td> 
<td>66</td> 
<td>72</td> 
<td>78</td> 
<td>84</td> 
<td>90</td> 
<td>96</td> 
</tr><tr> 
<td style="font-weight: bold;">7</td><td>7</td> 
<td>14</td> 
<td>21</td> 
<td>28</td> 
<td>35</td> 
<td>42</td> 
<td>49</td> 
<td>56</td> 
<td>63</td> 
<td>70</td> 
<td>77</td> 
<td>84</td> 
<td>91</td> 
<td>98</td> 
<td>105</td> 
<td>112</td> 
</tr><tr> 
<td style="font-weight: bold;">8</td><td>8</td> 
<td>16</td> 
<td>24</td> 
<td>32</td> 
<td>40</td> 
<td>48</td> 
<td>56</td> 
<td>64</td> 
<td>72</td> 
<td>80</td> 
<td>88</td> 
<td>96</td> 
<td>104</td> 
<td>112</td> 
<td>120</td> 
<td>128</td> 
</tr><tr> 
<td style="font-weight: bold;">9</td><td>9</td> 
<td>18</td> 
<td>27</td> 
<td>36</td> 
<td>45</td> 
<td>54</td> 
<td>63</td> 
<td>72</td> 
<td>81</td> 
<td>90</td> 
<td>99</td> 
<td>108</td> 
<td>117</td> 
<td>126</td> 
<td>135</td> 
<td>144</td> 
</tr><tr> 
<td style="font-weight: bold;">10</td><td>10</td> 
<td>20</td> 
<td>30</td> 
<td>40</td> 
<td>50</td> 
<td>60</td> 
<td>70</td> 
<td>80</td> 
<td>90</td> 
<td>100</td> 
<td>110</td> 
<td>120</td> 
<td>130</td> 
<td>140</td> 
<td>150</td> 
<td>160</td> 
</tr><tr> 
<td style="font-weight: bold;">11</td><td>11</td> 
<td>22</td> 
<td>33</td> 
<td>44</td> 
<td>55</td> 
<td>66</td> 
<td>77</td> 
<td>88</td> 
<td>99</td> 
<td>110</td> 
<td>121</td> 
<td>132</td> 
<td>143</td> 
<td>154</td> 
<td>165</td> 
<td>176</td> 
</tr><tr> 
<td style="font-weight: bold;">12</td><td>12</td> 
<td>24</td> 
<td>36</td> 
<td>48</td> 
<td>60</td> 
<td>72</td> 
<td>84</td> 
<td>96</td> 
<td>108</td> 
<td>120</td> 
<td>132</td> 
<td>144</td> 
<td>156</td> 
<td>168</td> 
<td>180</td> 
<td>192</td> 
</tr><tr> 
<td style="font-weight: bold;">13</td><td>13</td> 
<td>26</td> 
<td>39</td> 
<td>52</td> 
<td>65</td> 
<td>78</td> 
<td>91</td> 
<td>104</td> 
<td>117</td> 
<td>130</td> 
<td>143</td> 
<td>156</td> 
<td>169</td> 
<td>182</td> 
<td>195</td> 
<td>208</td> 
</tr><tr> 
<td style="font-weight: bold;">14</td><td>14</td> 
<td>28</td> 
<td>42</td> 
<td>56</td> 
<td>70</td> 
<td>84</td> 
<td>98</td> 
<td>112</td> 
<td>126</td> 
<td>140</td> 
<td>154</td> 
<td>168</td> 
<td>182</td> 
<td>196</td> 
<td>210</td> 
<td>224</td> 
</tr><tr> 
<td style="font-weight: bold;">15</td><td>15</td> 
<td>30</td> 
<td>45</td> 
<td>60</td> 
<td>75</td> 
<td>90</td> 
<td>105</td> 
<td>120</td> 
<td>135</td> 
<td>150</td> 
<td>165</td> 
<td>180</td> 
<td>195</td> 
<td>210</td> 
<td>225</td> 
<td>240</td> 
</tr><tr> 
<td style="font-weight: bold;">16</td><td>16</td> 
<td>32</td> 
<td>48</td> 
<td>64</td> 
<td>80</td> 
<td>96</td> 
<td>112</td> 
<td>128</td> 
<td>144</td> 
<td>160</td> 
<td>176</td> 
<td>192</td> 
<td>208</td> 
<td>224</td> 
<td>240</td> 
<td>256</td> 
</tr></table>
```

Answer (score 1):

Start the loop with 0 and add condition for desired output. Try this code,

```
echo "<table border =\"1\" style='border-collapse: collapse'>"; //creating the border outline
//echo "<td> x </td>";
for ($row = 0; $row <= 16; $row++) { // first loop
    echo "<tr> \n";
    for ($col = 0; $col <= 16; $col++) { //2nd loop
        if($row == 0 && $col == 0)
            echo '<td> x </td>';
        else if ($row == 0 && $col != 0)
            echo "<td>$col</td>";
        else if ($row != 0 && $col == 0)
            echo "<td>$row</td>";
        else {
            $p = $col * $row; //computing values
            echo "<td>$p</td> \n";
        }

    }
    echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>"; //closing the table
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: I'd also rely on css styling to decorate the columns as bold.`table tr:nth-child(1) > td{
  font-weight: bold;
}

table tr > td:nth-child(1) {
  font-weight: bold;
}` See https://jsfiddle.net/48tj5za7/